# Using environment variables in .lfsconfig file?

Tags: git-lfs

In order to have GitLFS integration, should add .lfsconfig file to root dir with the following structure

```
[lfs]
url = "https://myJfrogUserName:5NDQwMjU6Vzh5OW9hYTcmVmdGtuOjAxOjE3MjIlXb0hVS1RLRHNnRllpNEYwNmQw@mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/lfs/LFS-automation-gitlfs"
```

Is there a way to convert the "clear creds" to environment variables to something like the following ?

```
[lfs]
url = "https://${GIT_LFS_USER_NAME}:${GIT_LFS_USER_PW}@mycompany.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/lfs/zengo-test-automatio-gitlfs"
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables in your `.lfsconfig` file to provide dynamic values such as credentials

1. Set Environment Variables:

First, you need to set the environment variables in your system or in your CI/CD environment.
You can do this using your shell's syntax:

```js
export GIT_LFS_USER_NAME=myJfrogUserName
export GIT_LFS_USER_PW=5NDQwMjU6Vzh5OW9hYTcmVmdGtuOjAxOjE3MjIlXb0hVS1RLRHNnRllpNEYwNmQw
```

2. Update `.lfsconfig`:

Now, you can reference these environment variables in your .lfsconfig file:

```js
[lfs]
url = "https://${GIT_LFS_USER_NAME}:${GIT_LFS_USER_PW}@zengo.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/lfs/zengo-test-automatio-gitlfs"
```

Comment: nebil, already tried this approach which fails with the following 
"Downloading src/main/java/zengo/ImageComparison/Images/Home2.jpg (1.3 MB)
Error downloading object: src/main/java/zengo/ImageComparison/Images/Home2.jpg (48e98e1): Smudge error: Error downloading src/main/java/zengo/ImageComparison/Images/Home2.jpg (48e98e1e576410d7912a44f6c73f8d7b7aee825123649e1e1cb49b2084ba023c): batch request: missing protocol: "<unknown>"

Comment: Errors logged to '/Users/albert/Git/test-automation/.git/lfs/logs/20230807T163054.30442.log'.
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: src/main/java/zengo/ImageComparison/Images/Home2.jpg: smudge filter lfs failed"
20230807T163054.30442.log zsh: permission denied